# How to convert "2014-02-26T08:27:10.087-05:00" to date in Android?

Tags: android, date

This is the format i am getting from RSS Feed so how to convert it to date object in android?

```
2014-02-26T08:27:10.087-05:00
Feb 26 2014 8.27 AM -5.00 GMT
```

Comment: This question does not seem to be a duplicate of given link since it is about the specific ISO-8601 timezone-offset format using a colon. Android does not offer a suitable pattern, and Java only with version 7 or later (pattern symbol XXX). So here string preprocessing is necessary as workaround.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that your input strings seems to be really strange when it comes to timezone offset - there shouldn't be the colon.  In any case, the right way of dealing with this is to use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class:

```
String input = "2014-02-26T08:27:10.087-0500"
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date date = formatter.parse(input);
```

Have a look at the linked documentation to understand the patterns - then you just need to create patterns matching your input.